# How to find credentials on which a Diagnostic.Process is running

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

How to find out in c# visual studio 2012 web application on which credentials/Identity the `System.Diagnostic.Process` is running under programmatically?

Comment: Did you start the process?

Comment: You can do this [using WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @stuartd: an example of doing this in .NET would make a good answer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders [grumble]

Comment: Note that this is not specific to web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have added a reference to System.Management and you know the process ID you're interested in, you could use this code:

```
public void GetProcessOwner(int processId)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processId;
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query))
    {
        foreach (var queryObj in searcher.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>())
        {
            ManagementBaseObject outParams = queryObj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", null, null);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is owned by {1}\\{2}", queryObj["Name"], outParams["Domain"], outParams["User"]);
        }
    }
 }
```